# Add numbers to heading style without indent

Tags: ms-word

I have a heading with style `Heading 1`:

[image: No number]

I'd like the heading to be numbered so I modify the `Heading 1` style using the `Numbering` option and add a number. This works, but the result is indented in a way which is clearly wrong:

[image: Number with indent]

I'd like there to be no indenting at all, so try modifying the style using the `Paragraph` setting to remove the left indent. This results in another form of clearly wrong indentation:

[image: Number no indent]

How do I get the heading that any sane person would choose which would look like this (image manipulated to achieve goal!):

[image: Correct indentation]

Answer (score 1):

Alright look, after you added the `Numbering` option you right click on the format you are using. There you click on, which says "*Ändern...*" in my word and probably says something like "*change*" in yours.
[image: FirstPic]

This window should pop up, where you click on the option, highlighted in blue in the picture, and then on ok, this should do the trick.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want the number to be followed by a space rather than a tab.

If you follow the instructions in [this article](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)  by Shauna Kelly you will learn how to do that, and learn the correct way to set up numbering in Word.